# How to delete the rows that are older than a specific period from sqlite database

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, datetime

I have a table named scans. The table has 3 columns. `id, barcode text, and scanned DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. I want to have a query to delete the rows that are 30 days older. Initially, I used a query like this.

```
 "date(scanned) < date('now', '-30 day')";
```

But this wasn't working, those rows that are 30 days older were not deleted.
Then I tried this new query

```
"datetime(scanned / 1000, 'unixepoch') < datetime('now', '-1 month')";
```

and it deleted all rows including the rows that are younger than 30 days.
Can anyone tell me how to change my work to let the sqlite database only delete the rows that are 30 day older?

Comment: Please provide some sample data. (See [How to
format SQL tables in a Stack Overflow
post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96125) for how to add some.)

Answer (score 3):

Run this

```sql
DELETE FROM scans WHERE scanned < DATETIME('now', '-30 day')
```